# Как в Debian перейти с gnome на cinnamon через терминал?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gnome, cinnamon

Устанавливал себе debian 8 и выбрал окружение cinnamon. Он мне все равно поставил Gnome. Как перейти на Сinnamon не переустанавливая систему. Это можно сделать через терминал?

Comment: по дефолту отображается Gnome

Comment: А разве debian использует sudo?

Comment: bash: sudo: команда не найдена
вот что он пишет

Comment: dionisio@dionisio:~$ su apt install -y task-cinnamon-desktop
su: неверный ключ — «y»
Использование: su [параметры] [ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ]

Comment: так и не получилось

Comment: apt install -y task-cinnamon-desktop   Эту команду выполнил и reboot тоже но не появился cinnamon а остался gnome

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/index.html.ru

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.

Comment: вообще-то [cinnamon — это тоже gnome](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon). ну а в частности, сконфигурировать (уже установленную) x-сессию cinnamon на запуск по умолчанию: `update-alternatives --set x-session-manager /usr/bin/cinnamon-session`